Issue with ROS2 Humble and GZ Harmonic: Controller not functioning properly
I am using ROS2 Humble and Gazebo (GZ) Harmonic with the following packages installed:
sudo apt-get install gz-harmonic
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-ros-gzharmonic
sudo apt install ros-humble-ros2-control ros-humble-ros2-controllers
When launching my project, I am encountering errors related to the Controller Manager and the System Plugin:
Controller Manager Issues: Several spawners like arm_controller, diff_drive_base_controller, and joint_state_broadcaster are unable to connect to the /controller_manager/list_controllers service.

Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
System Plugin Error: The system plugin gz_ros2_control-system fails to load with the following error:

Failed to load system plugin [gz_ros2_control-system] : Could not find shared library.
Question: How can I ensure that the controller works properly and that the gz_ros2_control-system plugin loads successfully? Am I missing any dependencies or configuration steps?
I also fixed the missing lib:
[Err] [SystemLoader.cc:107] Failed to load system plugin: (Reason: No plugins detected in library)
Requested plugin name: [gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin]
Requested library name: [gz_ros2_control-system]
Resolved library path: [/opt/ws_moveit2/install/gz_ros2_control/lib/libgz_ros2_control-system.so]


Hi could you share your .launch.py? Are you running a ros2_control_node alongside the spawning of a gz_controller?

my main issue is now: [ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_broadcaster-11] [WARN] [1729699183.009640821] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers

Okay so if I am understanding you right:

You want to launch a robot which will be simulated in Gazebo Harmonic and plan and execute moves using MoveIt2 (move_group). As found in your Git launch.py link
The issue is no controller is loaded and activated.

A few things that you might want to check or try:

Is the joint_states topic included in gz_bridge.yaml? Like this:

- ros_topic_name: "joint_states"
  gz_topic_name: "/joint_states"
  ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/JointState"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.Model"
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS



Is the URDF file loaded which includes the gazebo controller? And does it include these?

...
<gazebo>
    <plugin filename="gz_ros2_control-system" name="gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin">
        <parameters>$(find robert_moveit_config)/config/ros2_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        <ros>                
            <remapping>/controller_manager/robot_description:=/robot_description</remapping>
        </ros>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
<ros2_control name="gazeboSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
        <plugin>gz_ros2_control/GazeboSimSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <!-- Insert all joint controller setup here -->
</ros2_control>
...


Try running the move_group_node manually instead of launching the generated move_group.launch.py. This gives you way more flexibility and control. MoveIt2_tutorials move_group.launch.py is a great example of this, but remove the ros2_control_node (because it is created from the gazebo plugin in the URDF) and edit the moveit_config to somthing like:

moveit_config = (
    MoveItConfigsBuilder(robot_name="robert", package_name="robert_moveit_config")
    .robot_description(file_path="absolute/path/to/description/urdf/with/GzController")
    #. additional non-standard settings
    .to_moveit_configs()
)


When working with Moveit2 this method increases readability as well.
More info about MoveItConfigBuilder

Since you're publishing robot_description already try spawning the robot from the /robot_description topic instead of loading the .xml. By editing:


gazebo_spawn_entity_action = Node(package='ros_gz_sim', executable='create', output='screen',
       arguments=['-string', robot_desc, '-name', 'robert', '-allow_renaming', 'true', '-x', x, '-y', y, '-z', '0.', '-Y', psi],)


to
gazebo_spawn_entity_action = Node(
    package='ros_gz_sim', 
    executable='create', 
    output='screen',
    arguments=[
        '-topic', 'robot_description', 
        '-name', 'robert', 
        '-allow_renaming', 'true', 
        '-x', x, '-y', y, '-z', '0.', '-Y', psi
    ],
)

